# No module named 'numpy'?

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\xil15102\Documents\example.py", line 1, in <module>
      import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I used command prompt to install numpy already!

```
c:\>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python27\arcgis10.6\lib\site-packages (1.9.3)
```

I also added a path to my scripts folder for python27 as well.

Comment: Do you work with multiple environments?

Comment: Could you add the results of running `where pip` (command line) and `import sys; print(sys.executable)` (in Python)?  It is ambiguous as to whether the pip you are running corresponds to the python interpreter.

Comment: verify the python version associated with your installed pip version with `pip -V`, you should see `(python 2.7)`

Comment: how did you install python?  Anaconda? (in which case, use conda)